# Problem turning off the computer

Tags: password

I have installed the latest ubuntu version 12.04 LTS,and everytime my wife logs on to her account we got problems to shut the computer off.It always returns to a log in promt on my account.Then its impossible to turn the computer off other than pressing the power button until it switches off by itself.All the passwords are also a hassle.
Is there somebody who can help me with this?
Best regards
Geir A

Comment: When you log out of your account, what actions do you perform?

Comment: Is the computer on a network where other users can login? Is anyone logging in as a root after logging in as a regular user?

Answer (score 1):

From a terminal while you're logged in try:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```